# How to solve Selenium multiprocessing error?

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to initialize 4 chromes and wrote the following:

```
def get_driver(i):
    print(i)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    return driver


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as p:
        drv = p.map(get_driver, [i for i in range(4)])

Error: multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: 
'[<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver
(session="466ec119aff28d62c3c621af2b190b0f")>]'. 
Reason: 'AttributeError("Can't pickle local object '_createenviron.<locals>.encodekey'",)'
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It's probably because you are trying to return `driver` from each process. It should work if you return something serializable.

Comment: What should be done if I want to return driver?

Comment: Why are you trying to return the driver from multiprocessing? If you initialize the driver within the pool you should complete all tasks related to that driver and close it before returning from the pool. If you are trying to create 4 drivers you do not need to use multiprocessing for that.

Answer (score 0):

the question is very old, but it can come in handy for someone, you do not need to transfer it to the pool but use it right away.

```
def get_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    print("open browser, current session is {}".format(driver.session_id))
    return driver

def open_page(url)
    driver = get_driver()
    browser.get(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = [['http://ya.ru'],['http://www.google.com']]
    p = Pool(2)
    p.starmap(open_page, tuple(url))
```